# how did they develop frontend, before node.js?

Tags: node.js, frontend

I'm learning frontend development, And in modern days we use frameworks like react, vue, angular etc. and also tools like webpack babel etc.

But all those frameworks and tools are installed by npm and run on nodejs.

Then, before nodejs came out, how did frontend work?

did they just insert script tags of jquery cdn?
and there were no build process neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have a look at how [Angularjs](https://angularjs.org/) works, that's pretty much what front-end was like.

Answer (score 0):

i remember we are only able to click the html file to debug.